# would a sturmey archer trigger shifter work on an shimano 333 3 speed hub?

Tags: shimano, maintenance, internally-geared-hub, sturmey-archer

Hi everyone i have an NOS shimano 333 3 speed hub set which was given down to me by my friend,all seems to be intact but the only thing missing is the shifter,but i do happen to have a few SA trigger shifters lying around,would it be possible to pair them up? and what other shifter option which i could use other than the original vintage shimano shifters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of Sheldon Brown's page on the subject is that the newer Nexus 3-speed shifters should work -- but will have the gear indicator in the wrong order (321=123).

I think it would be worthwhile trying the Sturmey shifter. For 3-speeds you need a position where the cable is tight, for one end, a position where the cable is loose, for the other end, and the correct adjustment in the middle. It should be easy to see if this is acheivable with a small amount of experimentation with the parts you already have.